# How to assign a different app name for system alerts in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertcontroller

Is it possible to override the application name in system level iOS alerts? *e.g.*:

> "App_Name" wants to access your location

I tried assigning different values to "Product Name", "Bundle name", and "Bundle display name" but none of them seemed to work for me.

Comment: Have you tried this Target - > Build Setting -> Packaging -> Product Name -> Change your app name.

Comment: You want the name under the icon on the home screen to be different from the name displayed in the alert, correct?

Comment: @Blisskarthik Yes, I followed those steps. App name appears on both places.

Comment: @DanielStorm Exactly.